# Call a onkeyup function when click on other button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have function which has keyup event on input field which is working fine.

I want to trigger this function also upon click on other button.

**Here is my function**

```
function validateChild(el) {
    var validated = {};
    console.log('Remove button clicked');
    var dateOfBirthField = $(el).find('.date_of_birth');

    $(dateOfBirthField).on("keyup", function () {
        var dateOfBirthValue = $(el).find('.date_of_birth').val();
        console.log('Check DoB');
        if(validateDateOfBirth(dateOfBirthValue, dateOfBirthField)){
            console.log('True');
            validated.dateOfBirth = true;
        } else {
            validated.dateOfBirth = false;
        }

        validateButton(validated);
    });
}
```

**I'm calling this function on document load**

```
function validateForms() {
    $(document).find(".child-form").each(function () {
        validateChild(this);
    });
}
```

**Here i have click event**

```
.on('click', '.removeButton', function (event) {
    validateForms();
});
```

When i click on this remove button it trigger but stop working after this

```
console.log('Remove button clicked');
```

How can i trigger keyup event also on this remove button, or there is better way to do this in javascript.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the element you pass in to the function in the working case the same as the `.child-form` you pass in from `validateForms()`?

Comment: Yes it has the same.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no only ignoring the keyup upon clicking on removeButton.

Comment: Have you got multiple forms? what tag is "child-form" assigned to? If possible, share your html or part of it. Why is needed to call validateForms() on document load? while the form is possibly empty. thanks if make it clear

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your three code blocks. Please try following three code blocks respectively.

**Your function**

```
function validateChild(dateOfBirthField) {
    var validated = {};
    var dateOfBirthValue = $(dateOfBirthField).val();

    console.log('Check DoB');
    if(validateDateOfBirth(dateOfBirthValue, dateOfBirthField)){
        console.log('True');
        validated.dateOfBirth = true;
    } else {
        validated.dateOfBirth = false;
    }

    validateButton(validated);
}
```

**Call this function on document load**

```
function validateForms() {
    $('.child-form').on('keyup', '.date_of_birth', function() {
        validateChild(this);
    });
}
```

**Click event**

```
.on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
    console.log('Remove button clicked');
    $('.child-form .date_of_birth').each(function() {
        validateChild(this);
    });
});
```